# columns component in form with has_many not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have two models job and schedule and there association is job has many schedules and schedule belong to job. My problem is that in active admin when i try to add column on f.has_many like:

```
panel 'schedules' do
  f.has_many :schedules do |sc|
    columns do
      column { sc.input :date, required: true }
    end
    columns do
      column { sc.input :reception }
      column { sc.input :start_at }
      column { sc.input :end_at }
    end
  end
end
```

Its shows columns as desire but when i click "Add new schedule" field are not appeared on columns as set. It would be great if anyone can help me. thank you

Comment: Do you see data getting posted in the logs?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get what you mean?

Comment: You need to post your web server logs. What ever window your webserver (`rails s`) is running, show the output when you click Add New Schedule. Also post your controller code.